# Loading unlooped gif-animation several times

Tags: javascript, html, electron

There is a code that displays a small gif animation in a table cell when clicked. Animation is unlooped. It is just an animated check mark.

**html:**

```
....
<script src="mega_script.js" defer></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="f(this);"></td>
    <td onclick="f(this);"></td>
    <td onclick="f(this);"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
....
```

**mega_script.js:**

```
function f(obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = '<img src="images/ok.gif">';
}
```

At the first click it is loaded and animated normally. The next clicks on the other table cells shows the already un-animated .gif. How can I overcome this?

If it is because of cache then how can I clear the .gif file from it?

Comment: Don't know if this will work, but you could try to bust the browser cache by adding a timestamp to the image URL: `obj.innerHTML = '<img src="images/ok.gif' + Date.now() + '">';`

Comment: @Patrick Hund. But how can it help? The image's adress is 'images/ok.gif' and not 'images/ok.gif20171020' for example.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant as a parameter like this: `obj.innerHTML = '<img src="images/ok.gif?timestamp=' + Date.now() + '">';`

Comment: @Patrick Hund. Thanks a lot! It does help. Although I don't understand why:)

Comment: I'll write up an answer and explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the browser caches the image after it has been loaded once, and the animation is run only when the image is fresh, not when the browser pulls it from its cache.

You can force the browser to reload the image by adding an arbitrary parameter to the URL that changes every time the image is referenced, like a time stamp, for example.

This method is also known as “cache busting”.

In your case, you can force the browser to reload the gif and retrigger its animation like this:

```
function f(obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = '<img src="images/ok.gif?timestamp=' + Date.now() + '">';
}
```

*Date.now()* gives us the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since 1970, so we can be reasonably sure that the URL will be slightly different every time the function is called.

Since the browser has no way of knowing that *ok.gif?timestamp=1508487387065* is the same file as *ok.gif?timestamp=1508487401817*, it will not use its cache and reload the image, giving you the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's clear to me. But doesn't it lead to overflow the cache space after some time?

Comment: I don't think that is something you have to worry about. The browser will manage the cache properly, you can be sure that the browser developers will have thought of that